# Highcharts breaks on axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a few years of sample data that I'd like to break at year end (12/31) of every year. Trying to implement this code from example [from API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.breaks)

```
breaks: [{ // break on last day of year
                from: Date.UTC(2008, 12, 31, 58),
                to: Date.UTC(2008, 12, 31, 59),
                repeat: 24 * 36e5 // not sure how to use this
            }],
```

is there a way to ignore the year in Date.UTC()? Also I'd like to repeat this every year. Tied numerous combos to no avail. Heres my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/help/c9e9ao2L/)

Comment: 24 * 36e5 equal to 1 day in millisecond in your case it should 365* 24 * 36e5

Comment: I didn't  understand  what u mean by >> way to ignore the year in Date.UTC()

Comment: in utc: month could be 0-11 where 0 is January and 11 is December.you using 12 as month parameter that means first month of next year(Jan 2009 in your case

Comment: You are missing broken-axis.js in fiddle.  But, I'm not sure the breaks feature is what you are looking for.  Breaks skip over groups of numbers in the axis.  It looks like you are trying to set a 1 second break.  That won't show as anything.  What exactly are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Thanks, i added broken-axis.js and your'e right. Client doesn't want lines connected between years. Plan B is while building data arrays for Highcharts, I'll add a year end (year/12/31) dummy line with all null values. Hopefully connectNulls: false will take care of the rest. Lot of work but I'm out of ideas. [jsfiddle so far](http://jsfiddle.net/help/q5kzduzk/)If you have any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Adding null value point will create a gap in a series plot if `connectNulls` is set to false (by default it is false).

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/c9e9ao2L/1/